# Using reduce to count groups of data within groups of data

Tags: javascript

As the title says, I'm trying to count groups of data within groups of data: My logic is to group all the data into states, then group date into years. so that the output should look like something like:

```
state,year,count
mo,1910,2
in,1910,1
il,1910,3
or,1910,4
co,1910,2
nd,1910,1
...
mo,1911,5
in,1911,4
il,1911,6
or,1911,2
co,1911,8
```

The CSV I'm using has a lot more columns that needed, I'm only interested in the columns `state` and `year`. My code below isn't working, any help would be great.

```
const countStates = filteredData.reduce((m, d) => {
    if(!m[d.year]){
      m[d.year] = {...d, count: 1};
      return m;
    }
    m[d.state];
    m[d.year];
    m[d.year].count += 1;
    return m;
},{});

const countedStates = Object.keys(countStates).map((k) =>  {
    const item  = countStates[k];
    return {
        state: item.state,
        year: item.year,
        count: item.count
    }
})
```

Edit

Example of the dataset I'm using:

```
datetime,city,state,country,shape,duration (seconds),duration (hours/min),comments,date posted,latitude,longitude 
10/10/1949 20:30,san marcos,tx,us,cylinder,2700,45 minutes,"This event took place in early fall around 1949-50. It occurred after a Boy Scout meeting in the Baptist Church. The Baptist Church sit",4/27/2004,29.8830556,-97.9411111
10/10/1949 21:00,lackland afb,tx,,light,7200,1-2 hrs,"1949 Lackland AFB&#44 TX.  Lights racing across the sky &amp; making 90 degree turns on a dime.",12/16/2005,29.38421,-98.581082
10/10/1955 17:00,chester (uk/england),,gb,circle,20,20 seconds,"Green/Orange circular disc over Chester&#44 England",1/21/2008,53.2,-2.916667
10/10/1956 21:00,edna,tx,us,circle,20,1/2 hour,"My older brother and twin sister were leaving the only Edna theater at about 9 PM&#44...we had our bikes and I took a different route home",1/17/2004,28.9783333,-96.6458333
10/10/1960 20:00,kaneohe,hi,us,light,900,15 minutes,"AS a Marine 1st Lt. flying an FJ4B fighter/attack aircraft on a solo night exercise&#44 I was at 50&#44000&#39 in a &quot;clean&quot; aircraft (no ordinan",1/22/2004,21.4180556,-157.8036111
10/10/1961 19:00,bristol,tn,us,sphere,300,5 minutes,"My father is now 89 my brother 52 the girl with us now 51 myself 49 and the other fellow which worked with my father if he&#39s still livi",4/27/2007,36.5950000,-82.1888889
10/10/1965 21:00,penarth (uk/wales),,gb,circle,180,about 3 mins,"penarth uk  circle  3mins  stayed 30ft above me for 3 mins slowly moved of and then with the blink of the eye the speed was unreal",2/14/2006,51.434722,-3.18
10/10/1965 23:45,norwalk,ct,us,disk,1200,20 minutes,"A bright orange color changing to reddish color disk/saucer was observed hovering above power transmission lines.",10/2/1999,41.1175000,-73.4083333
10/10/1966 20:00,pell city,al,us,disk,180,3  minutes,"Strobe Lighted disk shape object observed close&#44 at low speeds&#44 and low altitude in Oct 1966 in Pell City Alabama",3/19/2009,33.5861111,-86.2861111
10/10/1966 21:00,live oak,fl,us,disk,120,several minutes,"Saucer zaps energy from powerline as my pregnant mother receives mental signals not to pass info",5/11/2005,30.2947222,-82.9841667
10/10/1968 13:00,hawthorne,ca,us,circle,300,5 min.,"ROUND &#44 ORANGE &#44 WITH WHAT I WOULD SAY WAS POLISHED METAL OF SOME KIND AROUND THE EDGES .",10/31/2003,33.9163889,-118.3516667
10/10/1968 19:00,brevard,nc,us,fireball,180,3 minutes,"silent red /orange mass of energy floated by three of us in western North Carolina in the 60s",6/12/2008,35.2333333,-82.7344444
10/10/1970 16:00,bellmore,ny,us,disk,1800,30 min.,"silver disc seen by family and neighbors",5/11/2000,40.6686111,-73.5275000
```

And the code I used to filter out the data:

```
fs.createReadStream('./data/scrubbed.csv')  
    .pipe(readCSV())
    .on('data', (data) => CSV.push(data))
    .on('end', () => {
        let data = CSV.map((d) => {
            return {
                year: new Date (d.datetime).getFullYear(),
                state: d.state,
                country: d.country
            }
    });

filteredData = data.filter((d) => {
    return d.state !== "" && d.country === "us"
})
```

Which returns this (an example of the dataset):

```
[ { year: 1949, state: 'tx', country: 'us' },
  { year: 1956, state: 'tx', country: 'us' },
  { year: 1960, state: 'hi', country: 'us' },
  { year: 1961, state: 'tn', country: 'us' },
  { year: 1965, state: 'ct', country: 'us' }...
```

The above is what I'm trying to group twice using `reduce`

Comment: _"so that the output should look like something like"_. Where is the **input**. The most simplest to ask is like _"I have input(a valid javascript data which we can directly copy and use) which looks like. I want the output(a real js data) to be like this. This is what I have tried but it failed."_

Comment: @MaheerAli Does the input really matter when the op stated that they only needed the columns `state and year`?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you could use the data in the example output and go from there. The CSV may have too many columns to be included on SO, or whatever, sure they have a valid reason to not include it.

Comment: what is this line supposed to do: `m[d.state];` ?

Comment: @alfasin it's supposed to help create a unique row for when a state appears a in year, if that makes sense. But it doesn't work, what I thought would work doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code gets an array of states with the year and using `reduce` we are getting the count of each state grouped by year as

```js
var data = [
    { year: '1910', state: 'mo', country: 'us' },
    { year: '1910', state: 'in', country: 'us' },
    { year: '1910', state: 'il', country: 'us' },
    { year: '1910', state: 'mo', country: 'us' },
    { year: '1911', state: 'in', country: 'us' },
    { year: '1911', state: 'il', country: 'us' },
    { year: '1911', state: 'mo', country: 'us' },
    { year: '1911', state: 'in', country: 'us' }
];

var organizedData = data.reduce((acc, val, index) => {
  acc[val.state] = acc[val.state] || {};
  acc[val.state][val.year] = (+acc[val.state][val.year] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(organizedData);
```

Comment: Not sure whether you missed this after I edited the question after reading one of the comments. The outputs a little differento what I'm aiming for... I've updated again too, but thanks

Comment: @FeelingLikeAJabroni I have updated the code to change the input data format.

Comment: @FeelingLikeAJabroni I would appreciate if you could upvote as well